# cx_freeze & bundling files

Tags: python, cx-freeze

At present I am using pyinstaller for bundling my python application. I am equally migrating to pyGObject (due to pygtk being depreciated).

Now pyinstaller does not support pyGObject and I have as of yet not figured out the required hooks... One of the other downsides of pyinstaller is how it bundles into a single executable - it causes the company installed virus scanner to check quite intensively every time the exe is run ==> quite slow startup.

Looking into using cx_freeze due to the pyGObject & py3 support I note it does not have a single-executable option. That in itself isn't an issue if the working directory can be cleaned up, be it via the pyd/dll being bundled into a second zip or into a subdirectory.

Searching around (stackoverflow and other sites), it is illuded to that it can be done, but I am not getting the expected results. Any idea#s?

setup.py is based around this one: http://wiki.wxpython.org/cx_freeze

Comment: via 'build_exe':"dist/data"   I have been able to collate the dll/pyd files into a subdirectory, however I now recieve import errors. Adding sys.path+['./data'] as the path option doesn't resolve this.

Comment: The pyd/dll files are compiled libraries, which can't be loaded from a zip file (though it's possible to extract them from a zip file before the program needs them). Changing `sys.path` should work for the pyd files, but it's harder to change where DLLs load from  - see [this MSDN doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok solved:

1) setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
EXE1 = Executable(
    # what to build
    script = "foo.py",
    initScript = None,
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    targetDir = "dist",
    targetName = "foo.exe",
    compress = True,
    copyDependentFiles = True,
    appendScriptToExe = True,
    appendScriptToLibrary = False,
    icon = 'foo.ico'
    )

setup(
    version = "9999",
    description = "...",
    author = "...",
    name = "...",

    options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes,
                             "excludes": excludes,
                             "packages": packages,
                             "path": sys.path,
                             "append_script_to_exe":False,
                             "build_exe":"dist/bin",
                             "compressed":True,
                             "copy_dependent_files":True,
                             "create_shared_zip":True,
                             "include_in_shared_zip":True,
                             "optimize":2,
                             }
               },

    executables = [EXE1]
    )
```

2) foo.py header:

```
import os
import sys

if getattr(sys,'frozen',False):
    # if trap for frozen script wrapping
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin'))
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\library.zip'))
    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\tcl')
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\tk')
    os.environ['MATPLOTLIBDATA'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable),'bin\\mpl-data')
```