# move all cxFreeze files into a seperate directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, executable, cx-freeze

I want to move all files frozen from cxFreeze into a directory different than the directory of the executable.

I have been looking around sourceforge, and I haven't found any nice solutions. Here is what I have seen:

[Moving all the dll and pyd to a sub folder with cx-freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803616/moving-all-the-dll-and-pyd-to-a-sub-folder-with-cx-freeze?lq=1)

[cx_freeze & bundling files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754180/cx-freeze-bundling-files?rq=1)

The first one's answer is not very helpful, and I do not know how to specify the directory to use with it.The problem with the second one is that it only handles modules, and the matplotlib and tkinter packages, but how would an implementation of it be able to handle all packages? And also I want an init script with it, so the second one doesn't help much eighter.

Comment: The answer to the first question you link to, along with the comments, does demonstrate what you need, just not very clearly. The comment "i added this line" indicates which bit you'd need to change to specify the directory. Have a go at working it out.

Comment: Try using a shortcut.

Comment: That's what I am using right now, but I would prefer a way to put them in a separate directory