# Bundling an application, hide sources/libs?

Tags: python, binaryfiles

This question is not about how to bundle a python application into a exe, or a binary. I can (almost) figure that by myself, with all the doc on the internet.

My question is more about what the final user will be able to see about my program. And for my personal culture.

For example, with cx_freeze, if I try to compile my app, I end up with a build directory. Inside, I have the binary of my app, let's call it "gui". But around, I have a bunch of *.so files.
Basically, the user can see every lib I used to build my app. I thought (maybe naively) that if I could create a unique binary file, all the libs would be included in the binary, and so, not "visible" by the user.

Do I think right or is it completely wrong ? Is it possible to bundle all the libs into one single binary, and mask them ? (I know cx_freeze can't handle a single bundle file).

Comment: `*.so` files are binary, and fairly opaque. Is it really so important to hide them?

Comment: Hum not very, after what I read on SO. What about the .pyc files though ? I read the can be uncompiled to get the source code. I have plenty of them too.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [pyinstaller](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/2.0). With the `--onefile` switch you can bundle everything into one file. However, it only fully supports `python X2`. This is a [good tutorial to get started with it](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script) .

If you cannot use `pyinstaller`, you may want to try to use the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754180/cx-freeze-bundling-files).

EDIT:

After having read the cx_freeze [documentation](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables), it turns out that you cannot bundle everything into a single exe. You will have to create a self extracting file with `7zip` or `IEXPRESS` (if you are on Windows) that just unpacks all of your .so files.

Comment: Yes, I checked pyinstaller already. But as you said, it only supports python 2. And my app is python 3.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: I don't know, I had tried this answer before, but I think I didn't get the expected results. What is it supposed to do ?

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: I have updated my answer again. I am not sure it solves tour problem, but this is the only answer that I know of.